# Which Arduino-Board do I need?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, sensors

I want to use a single Arduino board and link it to both the ANALOG CO2 GAS SENSOR (MG-811 SENSOR) and ANALOG PH SENSOR - METER KIT. I was wondering if the Uno Rev 3 had enough pins or do I have to go with the Mega.

Comment: They are hardly going to use 4 pin each . That means u could almost any Arduino u can find.

Answer (score 1):

Nano board has a bunch of analog and digital pins. It does good and cheap. But for convenience UNO board is preferable for its large size easy handling and easy pin and wiring management.

Answer (score 0):

Uno has enough pins. You'll probably need an analog pin for each measured quantity, and you might want a few digital pins to turn them on or off or make mode changes, if any. The next question is: what your project meant to do, and does the Uno have enough memory to accomplish it? You will probably go quite a way with an Uno before your project exceeds its capabilities, unless you have some unusually stringent requirements.

Comment: Thank you, I am a beginner to Ardunio and want the CO2 and Ph sensor to collect data for a science experiment over time together. Are there any resources you can direct me to regards attaching 2 sensors to an Arduino or articles to help me better understand arduino.

Comment: That's a pretty wide-open question! :-) You'll need to narrow it down some to keep it manageable. Try searching for "Introduction to Arduino" and follow a few of those leads. Try running a few of the the example programs from the Arduino IDE. Make small alterations to the examples to get some some hands-on experience with- and "ownership" of the compile/upload process. Find a few tutorials that demonstrate using a sensor & build them. Even if it's just to measure a resistor. By then you'll have some better-focused questions to search for or to bring back here. Have fun!